# Check a task (li) on Todo List with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting to learn code, and after a few time spent on HTML / CSS I'm starting to learn JS. I started to create a Todo List, managed (with some help and some time) to be able to create tasks and add them to the list. I can also delete them.

My problem now is that I can't "check" them when they're done; I would like to change the text-decoration and the background color of the task when I click on a 'check' button (it will be aside the 'delete' button).

I searched for a few hours now and I can't find. I'm a true beginner at JS, I don't know a lot of things, just the basics. Can anyone help me please?

HTML:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
<!-- Boxicons CSS -->
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tdl2.css">
</head>
<body>


<div id="add" class="entete">
<h2>To-Do List!</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder ="Laver la voiture..."> 
<button type="button" id="button">Ajouter</button>

</div>

<ul id="list">
  
</ul>



<script src="tdl2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//SELECTORS
let taskInput = document.querySelector('#myInput');
let addTaskButton = document.querySelector('#button');
let taskList = document.querySelector('#list');
//EVENT LISTENERS

addTaskButton.addEventListener('click',addTask);

//FUNCTIONS

function addTask() {

    //PREVENT THE FORM FROM SUBMITING
    event.preventDefault();

    if(taskInput.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter a task!")
    }
    else {
         //CREATE TASK DIV
        let taskDiv = document.createElement('div');
        taskDiv.classList.add('task');

        //CREATE LI
        let taskLi = document.createElement('li');
        taskLi.innerText = taskInput.value;
        taskLi.classList.add('task-li');
        taskDiv.appendChild(taskLi);

        //DELETE BUTTON
        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="bx bx-eraser"></i>';
        deleteButton.classList.add('delete-btn');
        taskDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);

        taskList.appendChild(taskDiv);

        //CLEAR INPUT VALUE
        taskInput.value = '';


        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            taskDiv.remove()
        });

        //CHECK BUTTON
        let checkButton = document.createElement('button');
        checkButton.innerHTML = '<i class="bx bx-check"></i>';
        checkButton.classList.add('check-btn');
        taskDiv.appendChild(checkButton);

    }
}
```

[Here is a capture of my Todo List.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bnMA.png)

Comment: Your script already has everything it needs. You just have to adopt parts of it (_"I can also delete them"_). _"I would like to change..."_ can be achieved by adding/removing a CSS class, which is also already in your script.

Comment: The picture of your to-do list doesn't add anything useful and for future questions: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)"_ (Source: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Thanks for your anwers! I'll take note of that for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

So, you already have:

```
//CHECK BUTTON
    let checkButton = document.createElement('button');
    checkButton.innerHTML = '<i class="bx bx-check"></i>';
    checkButton.classList.add('check-btn'); 
    taskDiv.appendChild(checkButton);
```

You need to add listener, as you do with your delete button.

```
checkButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if (checkButton.classList.contains('checked-btn')) { // making toggle
        checkButton.classList.remove('checked-btn');
   } else {
        checkButton.classList.add('checked-btn');
 });
```

This if - else block will help you make todo task checked and unchecked.

The class that you add 'checked-btn' should be styled as you want in css.

For example:

```
.checked-btn {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice :) I tried your code, but didn't manage to make it work. When I look to the console, it says that 'checkButton is not defined'. Idk what to do now haha, everything seems okay, I even tried to replace 'let' by 'var' or 'const' and nothing changed.

Comment: Update: managed to make it work, I simply typed it at the wrong place in the code. But it modifies the button itself, not the li ^^

Comment: I realized that you want to affect only on your li element, not on button. You can try this: 
 // 'e' is an event from which you can get parent element and first child of paranet container for check button will be your li.
     checkButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const li = e.target.parentElement.firstChild;
   if (li.classList.contains('checked-btn')) { // making toggle
        li.classList.remove('checked-btn');
   } else {
        li.classList.add('checked-btn');
 }});

Comment: In fact it worked just after I answered your comment ;) instead of 'checkButton.classList.add' I typed 'taskLi.classList.add' and now it modifies the li itself :D thanks again!